# Move ViewState server-side

Tags: asp.net

Okay so I have an ASP.NET application and I'm trying to reduce the overhead for our pages (our users have PCs that average 10 years old).

One of the approaches is to move ViewState server-side. We've plenty of RAM.

I followed the most often cited pattern for doing this here: http://authors.aspalliance.com/robertb/articles.aspx?articleId=2

Because it was written 7 years ago, I had to update some obsolete functions, namely RegisterHiddenField to ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField and ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.

This seems to work fairly well, however as soon as I do an AJAX postback, I get the error

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
```

I also noticed that there are now two hidden "__VIEWSTATE" fields on each page with one of them being empty, and one of them having the numeric value from my class.  I think this is related to the issue -- perhaps the AJAX update is trying to reading from the empty one instead of the one with the value?

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: You want to remove some simple text values from an HTML page because your users have such ancient computers... but you are using AJAX updates???

Comment: @Andrew: AJAX is purely _good_ for performance.  (when used correctly)

Comment: @SLaks - On relatively modern systems that wouldn't choke on a couple extra kilobytes of plain text in the HTML, sure. But on decade-old systems which apparently have so little memory they can't handle a few K of extra, hidden data on a page?? It seems to me a much better optimization technique here would be to *limit* ViewState to what is truly needed, and stop asking the browser to do more 'lifting', when it is assumed to be an elderly weakling by default.

Comment: @Andrew: The choice is either to refresh the entire page, or use AJAX to refresh only a small portion of it.  I chose to refresh only a small portion.  So yes, AJAX is a performance boost.

Comment: @msigman -and you are going to end up losing a lot of developer performance because what you really should be doing here is limiting viewstate... not eliminating it.. or just use a framework that doesn't start with ViewState in the first place, like ASP.NET MVC (probably not an option if you already have a working app)

Comment: @SLaks & @msigman - I am *not* saying you should not be using AJAX, really. I'm saying you need to consider the point of diminishing returns. You've hit that point hard, with your nose; and it's a big brick wall... nevermind the flimsy sheetrock covering it.

Comment: I totally agree; we need to trim down viewstate as much as possible no matter if it's stored in session or sent to the client in a hidden field.  That makes sense.  This is a first step which would hopefully provide immediate benefit.  We will still work to limit viewstate usage per page, but that takes more time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is not to use the provided example at all.  It's old and outdate, and there is a much better solution provided by the framework itself now.

```
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
    get { return new SessionPageStatePersister(this); }
}
```

I just added those 4 lines to my BasePage class and voila - instant ~30% page size reduction and it works fine with the AJAX updates.

Comment: I knew you'd find a way that didn't involve eliminating ViewState :)

Comment: This reduced my page size dramtically. And the page loads much faster for me / is more responsive

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have not done anything to tell the MS AJAX framework about your new, server-side ViewState mechanism; it is getting the new values, which are simply trimmed-down keys that point to where to find it in the Session object. The AJAX framework knows nothing about that.

Reducing ViewState is most easily done by disabling it on controls where it's not needed at all. If you are using ASP.NET 4.0, you can do even better - disable it by default on the whole page, then only enable it where you need it.

Comment: Hmm, this makes sense.  However, I ended up abandoning that whole scheme and using the built in .NET SessionPageStatePersister class instead.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever you can't do both. You should *always* try to reduce the ViewState, no matter where it's stored, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheSessionObjectAndMoreWrongheadedness.aspx

And use Http compression.